# How can I (as the app developer) get notified when a user leaves a review of my app on Google Workspace Marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We've just published our first app in Google Workspace Marketplace (a google docs add-on) and can't figure out how, or if, it is possible to setup an email or other notification (slack notification would be cool) for our Customer Success team to be notified when a user leaves a review of the app.

Appreciate that if we get thousands we will probably turn the notifications off (or filter them in some way), at this early stage though, we're very eager to act on any feedback.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Disclaimer: I am creator of [Obsei](https://github.com/obsei/obsei), and this might be biased answer.

You can try [Obsei](https://github.com/obsei/obsei): an open-source low-code AI powered automation tool.
It can monitor App and Play stores for customer reviews and send notification Slack when someone add review there. Also Obsei can classify review contextually to classify it into issue categories. Refer below image.[Obsei workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jj8H.png)

All of these can be achieved free without any cloud hosting requirement. Refer [link](https://github.com/obsei/demo-workflow-action) for more detail.

Happy to answer any queries in this regards.